# Null value in database relation using EF code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two Class Customers and MembershipType and has a structure. When creating the database, The column MembershipType has null value. How can i fix it?

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerGender { set; get; }
    public byte Age { set; get; }
    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsLetter { set; get; }
    public MembershipType MembershipType{ get; set; }
    public byte MembershipTypeId { set; get; }
}


public class MembershipType
{
    [Key]
    public byte MemebershipId { set; get; }
    public short SignUpFee{ get; set; }
    public byte DurationInMonth { set; get; }
    public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
}
```

Customers Table

```
  CusId CustName  CusGender Age  IsSub.. MembershipTypeId  MemberShipType_Membershipid
   1     Jobin       Male    27      0          2            NULL
```

Migration:

```
  CreateTable(
            "dbo.Customers",
            c => new
                {
                    CustomerId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    CustomerName = c.String(),
                    CustomerGender = c.String(),
                    Age = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                    IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    MembershipTypeId = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                    MemebershipTypes_MemebershipId = c.Byte(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CustomerId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.MembershipTypes", t => t.MemebershipTypes_MemebershipId)
            .Index(t => t.MemebershipTypes_MemebershipId);
```

Comment: When you instert a customer or when equals the MembershipType column with NULL?

Comment: @C1sc0 When inserting value in customer, it is NULL

Comment: Can you please show some code where you inserting the data?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of possible problems.

1. Try consistent spelling...
   Customer has a "MembershipTypeId" foreign key but the primary key of the "MembershipType" is "MemembershipId".
   What happens if you make the key of MembershipType MembershipTypeId? Could the convention-based configuration of EF be getting confused?
2. EF does not really like 1-to-1 relationships...when it creates them it wants the primary key of the dependent to be the the same value as the primary key of the primary http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `MembershipTypeId` field in both the `Customer` and `MembershipType` to `int`, delete the existing migration and add a new migration again and it will pick the `MembershipTypeId` field as a foreign key

Otherwise, you have to declare the relationship using Fluent API inside the Context class

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem as follows: put up a `[Required]` above the `MembershipTypeId` and `[ForeignKey("MembershipTypeId")]` above the `MembershipType` property

```
public class Customer
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string CustomerGender { set; get; }
   public byte Age { set; get; }
   public bool IsSubscribedToNewsLetter { set; get; }

   [Required]
   public byte MembershipTypeId { set; get; }

   [ForeignKey("MembershipTypeId")]
   public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
}


public class MembershipType
{
   [Key]
   public byte MemebershipId { set; get; }
   public short SignUpFee { get; set; }
   public byte DurationInMonth { set; get; }
   public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
}
```

### Update

It's better you delete this migration and create a new, because entity maybe be lost.